# System.Data.MissingPrimaryKeyException: 'Table doesn't have a primary key.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am writing code on Delete event on gridview but its throwing error

**'Table doesn't have a primary key.'**

I check my table primary key is already there in table. And i also try to set the **PrimaryKey** property of my **DataTable** object before call Find But still same error I am facing

Where i am doing wrong ?

**Code:**

```
protected void dgDepots_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
        {
            int i = dgDepots.FindVisibleIndexByKeyValue(e.Keys[dgDepots.KeyFieldName]);
            Control c = dgDepots.FindDetailRowTemplateControl(i, "dgCustomers");
            e.Cancel = true;
            dt = (DataTable)Session["DataSet"];
            DataColumn[] keyColumns = new DataColumn[1];
            keyColumns[0] = dt.Columns["LineItemID"];
            dt.PrimaryKey = keyColumns;
            dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows.Find(e.Keys[dgDepots.KeyFieldName]));
        }
```

What should i change in that

Comment: I think you can not apply `LINQ find` without `EF entity`. For dataset use `dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows.Where(x=> x.YourProperty==e.Keys[dgDepots.KeyFieldName]).FirstOrDefault());` .

Comment: @NagibMahfuz I change my code as you suggested but i am getting error on Where.

Comment: @NagibMahfuz can you modify my given code in that Please

Comment: Here `x.YourProperty` is the `datatable` column name you want to match with `e.Keys[dgDepots.KeyFieldName]` property. So please check your `datatable` and replace  `x.YourProperty` with `x.dtatablematchcolumn`.